# How to find eloquent models based on the absense of matching dates in parent and child models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, model

In Laravel how do I make a selection where a child model's `created_at` property doesn't match the parent model's `next_date` property?

Assuming I have an Eloquent model relationship where a parent model `Subscription` has many child models `Saving`, and I want to retrieve all parent models where the `created_at` property of the most recent child model is not equal to the `next_date` property of the parent model, how do I go about this?

I got stuck around here:

```php
$savings = Subscription::whereNotNull('interval')
   ->whereNot('interval', 'manual')
   ->whereDoesntHave('savings', function ($query) {
     // I'm not entirely sure of what I should do here
     // This does not work     
     $query->whereDate('created_at', date('Y-m-d'));
     // date('Y-m-d') should rather refer to the parent model's created_at property.
   })
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a method in your Subscription model to get the last saving:

```
public function lastSaving()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Saving::class)->latest();
}
```

And then call using subquery:

```
$savings = Subscription::whereNotNull('interval')
   ->whereNot('interval', 'manual')
   ->whereDoesntHave('savings', function ($query) {  
     $query->where('created_at', 'sub.next_date')->from('subscriptions as sub');
   })
   ->with('lastSaving')
   ->get();
```

Documentation for subqueries here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#subquery-where-clauses